# How to change the color of the spinner NOT the dropdown items?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have added a Spinner with a custom listadapter which uses this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@drawable/default_spinner_item_text"
    android:text="Sample Text"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="7.5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/default_spinner_item"
    android:paddingTop="7.5dp">

</TextView>
```

Drawable default_spinner_item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/default_button_text_color" />


    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <item android:state_single="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <item android:state_active="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <item android:state_first="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />


    <item android:drawable="@color/default_button_border_color" />
</selector>
```

The spinner allways gets the same color as the dropdown items...

I have tried all the states but it seams impossible to make the spinner item background transparent and the dropdown list colored (default_button_border_color).

**@Solved**

This is my Adapter:

```
public class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private int _resource;
    private Typeface _typeFace;

    public CustomSpinnerAdapter(MainActivity context, int resource, List<String> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
        _resource = resource;
        _typeFace = context.getDefaultAppTypeFace();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView view = (TextView)super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if(convertView == null)
           view.setTypeface(_typeFace);
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public TextView getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView view = (TextView) super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
        if(convertView == null)
           view.setTypeface(_typeFace);
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

I now use two layouts, one for the view and one for the dropdownview. Another error in my code was that I called super.getView(position, convertView, parent); in the getDropDownView ovverride.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just make two layout with desired color and set it like following:

```
ArrayAdapter<yourObjecttype> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<yourObjecttype(this,R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.dropdown_layout);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do it from code.

The `BaseAdapter`, `ArrayAdapter` and others implement an interface called [`SpinnerAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html)

This interface provides a method called `getDropDownView`. Using this method for the DropDown elements and the "normal" `getView` method for the selection should do the trick.

If you're using `ArrayAdapter`, you can also use it's `setDropDownViewResource` method

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/myspinner_background" />
```

under **Drawable** folder place this **myspinner_background.xml**

myspinner_background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item   android:drawable="@drawable/big_drop_down_selected" 
            android:state_focused="false" 
            android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item   android:drawable="@drawable/big_drop_down"/>

</selector>
```

in Activity

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> adpFromStation;
Spinner spnrFromStation = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
adpFromStation = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,StationNamesList);
        adpFromStation.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spnrFromStation.setAdapter(adpFromStation);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use XML file to change the spinner color

```xml
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/idSpinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
    android:background="@color/white" />
```

Use Java file to change spinner color programmatically

```java
idSpinner = findViewById(R.id.idSpinner);
idSpinner.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
```